# Create a RecylerView inside a Fragment without having setUp the Fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a Fragment 'FR_MyItems' and inside it I create a RecyclerView 'myItemsRecyclerView' by using an ArrayList 'myItemsList'. When I navigate to the Fragment the RecyclerView the Fragment is created and the RecyclerView is set up and it works fine.

However, now I want to add items to this Recyclerview from another class by using the static method 'public static void insertItem(String ItemType, String ItemName)'. The problem is that if I have not navigated to the Frament 'FR_MyItems' before, the RecyclerView is not set up and I get a null pointer expection when trying to do something with the RecyclerView.

So my question now is how can I create this RecyclerView without having navigated to the Fragment that hosts it? In my initial class all the RecyclerView variables were not static but now I have to make them static such that I can access them from other classes.

Here you see the Java code of the 'FR_MyItems':

```
package com.example.td.bapp;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.td.bapp.databinding.MyItemsBinding;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;


public class FR_MyItems extends Fragment {




    private static RecyclerView myItemsRecyclerView;
    private static MyItemsAdapter myItemsAdapter;
    private static RecyclerView.LayoutManager myItemsLayoutManager;

    private static ArrayList<MyItemsItem> myItemsList;

    public FR_MyItems() {

    }


    public static FR_MyItems newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FR_MyItems fragment = new FR_MyItems();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    }


    private MyItemsBinding binding;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = MyItemsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        createExampleList();
        buildRecyclerView();
        return binding.getRoot();

    }
    public void createExampleList () {
        myItemsList = new ArrayList<MyItemsItem>();
        myItemsList.add(new MyItemsItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Item 1", "C", "20:34, 12.12.20"));
        myItemsList.add(new MyItemsItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Item 2", "A", "21:34"));
        myItemsList.add(new MyItemsItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Item 3", "B", "20:34"));
    }

    public  void buildRecyclerView () {
        myItemsRecyclerView = binding.recyclerView;
        myItemsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        myItemsLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext());
        myItemsAdapter = new MyItemsAdapter(myItemsList);

        myItemsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(myItemsLayoutManager);
        myItemsRecyclerView.setAdapter(myItemsAdapter);

        myItemsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new MyItemsAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                changeItemStatus(position, "Clicked");
            }
        });
    }


    public static void insertItem(String ItemType, String ItemName) {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm z, dd-MM-yyyy");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
        int position =myItemsList.size();

        String status = "good";
        if(FR_LanguageSelection.currentLanguageOfTheApp.equals(FR_LanguageSelection.LANGUAGE_GERMAN)) {
            status = "gut";
        }

        if (ItemType.equals(DataBaseEntries.ITEM2)) {
            myItemsList.add(position, new MyItemsItem(R.drawable.ic_android, ItemName, status, sdf.format(new Date())));
            myItemsAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
        }

    }



    public void removeItem (int position) {
        myItemsList.remove(position);
        myItemsAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

    }

    public void changeItemStatus (int position, String newStatus) {
        myItemsList.get(position).setStatusProperty(newStatus);
        myItemsAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate every comment and would be quite thankful for your help.

Comment: I would suggest to use `Room` database. Just add the items you need to show in the recyclerview to the database and in the fragment displaying the recyclerview, just query the database and display the data

Comment: Thanks Sekiro for your answer. Basically the items that should be displayed are dynamic and I do not know them before. They are determined by the user outside the shown Fragment. This is why I can't use a database (and if so I'd not use Room, but SQLiteOpenHelper as I already have experience with it ).

Comment: `Basically the items that should be displayed are dynamic and I do not know them before` that shouldn't be a problem. Just store the values of the dynamically created items and use those values to populate the recyclerview

Comment: `and if so I'd not use Room, but SQLiteOpenHelper as I already have experience with it`--- Indeed a big mistake, `Room` is just an abstract layer over the `SqlLite database` created to do the heavy lifting for ya, but if you still prefer using sqlite directly instead of room, be my guest

Comment: @VanessaFthe answer suggested by Sekiro sounds like a proper way to solve query. you should minimize the use of static methods / Views also look in to  room + livedata

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Okay I will try to use a database for my issue. But as I have already implemented everything using SQLOpen helper I do not want to use Room because it is quite time-consuming to learn new libraries every time given that I just use Android in my spare time. Further I think that SQLOpenHelper is quite easy to use and I don't think that Room is really that much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very clear but I will try to help you

As the others said it would be best for you to use Viewmodel, livedata and room. In the beginning it is a little difficult but later it is much easier and faster to work...

If you do not want to use the room, you may use the viewmodel to inform the fragments in the activity about changes

example:

1. Create ViewModel class like this

   ```
    public class MyItemsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

        private final MutableLiveData<Boolean> refresh;

        public MyItemsViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
            super(application);
            this.refresh  = new MutableLiveData<>();
        }

        public void setRefresh(Boolean ref) {
            this.refresh.setValue(ref);;
        }

        public MutableLiveData<Boolean> getRefresh() {
            return this.refresh;
        }




        public static class Factory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {

            private final Application application;

            public Factory(@NonNull Application application) {
                this.application = application;
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
                //noinspection unchecked
                return (T) new MyItemsViewModel(this.application);
            }
        }

    }
   ```

In Activity where is your FR_MyItems Fragment, (probably your main activity) copy/paste this code (only code below TODO in comment)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     //TODO copy this in onCreate method
     MyItemsViewModel.Factory factory = new MyItemsViewModel.Factory(getApplication());
     viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(MyItemsViewModel.class);
     subscribe();
}
```

and copy/paste complete this method

```
private void subscribe() {
        viewModel.getRefresh().observe(this, refreshed -> {
            if(refreshed){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

3. In FR_MyItems Frgament

copy this (compete function)

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if(getActivity() == null) return;
        MyItemsViewModel.Factory factory = new MyItemsViewModel.Factory(requireActivity().getApplication());
        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), factory).get(MyItemsViewModel.class);
        subscribe();
    }

    private void subscribe() {
        viewModel.getRefresh().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), refreshed -> {
            if(refreshed){
                //TODO load data from sqlite database and update your MyItemsAdapter with new data list 
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Refreshed Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                viewModel.setRefresh(false);
            }
        });
    }
```

4. In your fragment for creating new item (if exist)

copy this

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            if(getActivity() == null) return;
            MyItemsViewModel.Factory factory = new MyItemsViewModel.Factory(requireActivity().getApplication());
            viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), factory).get(MyItemsViewModel.class); 
        }
```

And finaly when you insert new item do it

copy this in method after inserting

```
viewModel.setRefresh(true);
```

it will reload adata and refresh your list in FR_MyItems

Also if you don't want insert item in database you can create List myItemsList in MyItemsViewModel create get,set,add methods and observe it from fragments

Add this in class MyItemsViewModel

```
    private List<MyItemsItem>> items
    private final MutableLiveData<List<MyItemsItem>> myItemsList;
        public MyItemsViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
            super(application);
            items= new ArrayList();
            this.refresh  = new MutableLiveData<>();
            this.myItemsList  = new MutableLiveData<>();
        }
    public addItem(MyItemsItem item){
            items.add(item);
            myItemsList.setValue(items);
        }
//TODO create set, get and add methods for list
```

and observe it in your activity or fragments

```
viewModel.getMyItemsList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), list -> { 
    //TODO update adapter with list
});
```

Also you can use it on other way if you want use notifyItemChanged and don't want to swap data in adapter every time

This is possible in the activity and its fragments.

If you want to refresh the lists between activities you will have to use room or some other way to do so...

EDITED 2

**This image is only for your case and it will be deleted soon**

In other cases the data is managed (CRUD) through the ViewModel and repository or repositories not in View-UI

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks for the interesting solution (I upvoted it). As I have no experience whatsoever with the viewModel (I do not even know what it is and when and how it should be used), I will first try it the the database (SQLiteOpenHelper) solution and see whether it works. If it does not work, I will try the ViewModel altough for me it seems to be more complex.

Comment: I understand you, it was confusing for me at first too, but from this time distance this is a much easier way... The previous code can be understood very quickly through one tutorial and of course you can use it with SQLiteOpenHelper (without room) - just to refresh activity and fragments for changes... happy coding

Comment: Thanks for the comment adnandann. Basically I do not need the viewmodel and livedata at all . A database is fully enough for it. So I do not understand why I should use the Viewmodel and by doing so increasing the complexity. What advantages does the viewData approach have compared to just using the database? Why add unecessary complexity? I had a look into a ViewModel tutorial and for it seems to be quite difficult. The only advantage that was mentioned there is that the data is available also when rotating the screen. This is not a big advantage for me considering the increased complexitiy.

Comment: I had a look again at your code and for me it is extremely complex and difficult to understand. Fuher, there is so much additional code for something quite simple (just adding one item into a list). So I am not going to use the Livedata and Viewmodel approach. Still, I want to thank you for your answer and I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: Thanks for the comment adnandann. Would you mind telling me what advantages the LiveData and ViewModel approach has in your eyes compared to just using a database?

Comment: it is a design pattern that is not strictly tied to the room ... you can fetch data from api for example. 
In your case, I suggested that you use this pattern to simplify sharing data or state between the activity and the fragments in it, so without using room. 
It's pretty simple: Activity and Fragment are VIEWs, ViewModel keeps data or state (LiveData). 
Activity and fragments observe for data/state changes and update views.

Comment: **from above
In code that I posted there is no room. In your case you will insert new item in database (with SQLiteOpenHelper) and on success you will change state in ViewModel for refresh to true.
The fragmnt that displays the list observe the refresh state in ViewModel and when is true it will load data from the database (SQLiteOpenHelper) and set refresh state to false.
Also if you need only myItemsList (without data list from database) your ViewModel can hold myItemsList with add,set,get methods... In one fragment add item, another one will refresh recyclerview data list

Comment: just copy/paste my code and when you insert new item just do viewModel.setRefresh(true)... to see how it works...

Comment: Thanks adnandann for your comment and effort. I really appreciate it. Basically I wanted to know what the advantage of your posted ViewModel LiveData approach is compared to just using a database query? As said before, for me the code is extremely confusing and complex and I have about 25 Fragments in my App meaning that I would have to adjust all of them with something that I do not understand which is extremely likely to cause errors. So I just want to know the benefits of the ViewModel-LiveData approach such that I can evaluate whether it is worth adjusting my code

Comment: In my case I would just store the information in SQLOpenHelper and then when the user navigates to the Fragment would always create the whole RecyclerView in the onCreateView-method of the Fragment by quering the database. This is quite easy and you do not need nearly as much code as in your approach. So what is the advantage of your approach that 'justifies' the highly increased complexitiy and code size? I'd appreciate any further comments from you.

Comment: Some of advantages: easy communication between activity and fragments in it, lifecycle-aware, survives rotation, separation of concerns (you don't have to keep all the code in activity that is UI class).  Every activity should have its own ViewModel that can use the fragments that are in that activity.
Activity is UI/View class and it shoud only contain logic that handles UI, all about data shoud be in ViewModel (or Repository if you use it)
You don’t have to apply this to all the fragments. You can only try the above code in the activity and its fragments related to this issue. step by step

Comment: Thanks adnandann  for your comment. Basically all of my 25 Fragments are related to this issue. So I would have to adjust all of them I think. In my App you can't strictly separate the UI and the data. I have to use DatabaseEntries to construct the UI, this is why I can't separate them

Comment: And what do you mean by saying "Every activity should have its own ViewModel that can use the fragments that are in that activity."
. I use a single Activity-MultipleFragments approach. What consequences would this have

Comment: [I mean this... click](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/images/final-architecture.png). You don't have to use it for everything, just what you need. it can be one small class and a couple of lines of code in two fragments... step by ste. however, to better understand you have to look at some simple tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have a lot of datahandling in my Fragments (UI) classes as I think I can't really separate the UI and the Datahandling in general. Can I still use the View-Model LiveData approach while maintaining the datahandling within the UI classes of the Fragments?

Comment: Thanks adnandann for your comment. Any comment on my last comment? I'd appreciate any further comment from you.

Comment: You can implement the basics where you need communication between a fragments or activity 
Viewmodel is data or state holder for his View/s (Activity and Fragments) 
In this answer, I suggested that you use the ViewModel only for refresh state, nothing more.
You don't have to change your code.
When you insert the data into the db in the CretorFragment you change the refreshstate to true and the second fragment will be notified to refresh the list... its easy. nothing more
You don't have to use this pattern you can just try to implement this answer by copy/paste and see what happens

Comment: Thanks adnandann for your comment. Can I also just use the database without your posted code? I am quite sure that if I use your posted code it will be quite difficult to update the recylerview as this will create many errors that I do not understand as I do not understand your posted code at all.

Comment: Check image in answer. I'm afraid I can't help you enough because the code you're posting doesn't tell me much more about your algorithm and I don't know what you want with insertItem (in the database or only in RecylcerView) and where you call it from (the dialog or viewpager fragment). try copy/paste code to the bottom of your activities and snippets to see what happens...

Comment: Thanks adnandann  for your comment and effort. I really appreciate it. Basically the insert method should just insert a new entry in the Recylerview at the beginning. The information about the new item comes from a database which is added in another activity

Comment: I only have one Activity (I use a single-activity multiple-fragments approach). Honestly I do not understand at all what I should do with your code as it has a high complexity. Your write about a new class "Create class" (1) and then you also say something about the In FR_MyItems Frgament (3) and about "In Activity where is your FR_MyItems Fragment" (2).

Comment: You should copy this code into your activity and fragments but if you don't understand it then don't do that ... first you have to go through some tutorials to learn

Comment: Thanks for the comment adnandann. So do I have to copy your posted code in every activity and in every fragment (I have about 25 fragments)?

Comment: Please, first find some tutorials to learn more about this...

Comment: Do you know a good tutorial for learning about this?

Comment: Thanks adnandann for yoru comment. And what about my core question: What if I do not use the approach that you suggested and just use a database with a RecylerView. Is this also possible and does my simple approach have any cruical drawbacks? I'd appreciate any further comment from you.

Comment: This is not a good way, and I don't know if it can work at all... First you have to learn some about "When to use static in java" then "How to communicate between fragments" ... BUT you better lose 7 days to learn ViewMode (MVVM pattern) than spend time on things that are deprecated. I also had problems in the beginning but now I would never go back to the old way...[start here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) ... if you still don't want, then use the interface to communicate with fragments

Comment: Thanks adnandann for your further comment. I really appreciate your effort. Why do I have to first learn "When to use static in java"? Basically I understand what static means.

Comment: This is an unusual way that I haven't seen or tried, and I'm not sure what you want ... I don't have an insight into the complete code, but from what I see, there is certainly a better way to do that. static means only one copy of value for all instances/objects. I don't know why you use it in a fragment if you don't need those fields anywhere else... You said that you have one activity with several fragments, what I see is little to give you any other instructions than what I've already written. If you want to work with multiple fragments, you have to solve it in a different way than this

Comment: ´Thanks adnandann for your further comment and effort. What are you referring to when saying that " I don't know why you use it in a fragment if you don't need those fields anywhere else". I do not use static methods for the RecyclerView anymore (but just for the database). Basically I have one Activity and multiple fragments. In one Fragment I can order some items which are then copied into the database. The current fragment with the Recyclerview should display the items that are in the database.

Comment: And another Fragment should be able to change some variables (Status) of the items in the RecyclerView. Can I do this without an ViewModel and LiveData? Or is it enough if I just use LifeData without a ViewModel or just the ViewModel without the LiveData? I think learning two new things (LifeData and ViewModel) will be way to timeconsumping for me especially considering the high level of complexity of LifeData and ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks a lot adnandann for your tremendous effort. I really appreciate it. As I have no experience with github, I really do not know what to do. How can I integrate your code into mine (which classed and res files do I have to copy and paste)? Further, my project is quite complex having more than 30 Fragments and classes. I don't have a clue how and where I can include your suggested code (and the ViewModel or LiveData approach) into my application.

Comment: Updated: I created this for you to see how things work... It could have been better but I didn't have enough time ... Some things are deprecated so replace them... You can not integrate this in your app, you can learn and create for your needs... Android Studio -> File -> New -> Project from Version Control -> select Git and paste this URL https://github.com/adnandann/mvvm.git -> Click Clone button (wait some time and install app on your phone)

Comment: Thanks adnandann for your answer and effort. I had a look into the code and it did not really help me as i do not understand it. So my basic question still remains: Do I have to use LiveData and or the View Model approach?

Comment: Hhere again a short description of my app: So I have a Client that uses a single Activity multiple Fragments approach.  In one of those fragments a Recylerview is shown. In the other fragments the user can insert new items into the recylerView. A Server application can change the status of the items in this RecyclerView.

Comment: No you don't have to, you can use interfaces to communicate fragments and activities - the old way... Did you install my sample app on your phone?

Comment: Thanks adnandann for your comment. Okay this means that I do not have to use LiveData and ViewModel approach which would be quite time consuming to learn. What is the downside of the old way? I read the tutorial about ViewModel you gave me the link to but I did not really like it as it was difficult to understand. Do you know a better tutorial where the topic is explained in a more comprehensive way?

Comment: I used your app in the Emulator of Android Studio but honestly it did not help at all. I still do not understand how I could apply the approaches you used in my App.

Comment: Hi adnandann. Thanks for your effort. Bascially now I just use the database and the recyclerview without the live data or view model approach and it works perfectly for inserting items into the RecyclerView and  displaying them.

Comment: Now I want to get a step further and I would like to change the status of the items in the recylerview from an other app (that can be regarded as a 'server' while the normal app can be regarded as a 'client'). My question now is, what is the easiest way of doing this. (Basically there should also be communication from the client to the server). Is it just possible to change the corresponding entry in the database and notify the RecylerView creation method when the server triggers something? This way I would not need any LiveData and Viewmodel and thus reduce the complexity of the app.

Comment: Communication between apps in this way is not possible, there are other ways that are not related to the question and topic...

Comment: Thanks adnandann for your comment and effort. I really appreciate it. Okay let's not consider the communication between different apps but rather focus on the RecyclerView in a Fragment. As written before, it is created when a certain Fragment is being displayed and it used a Database for generating its items. Let's say an external source (maybe a webservice or even another fragment of the same app) wants to change the property of one of some items in the recyclerview. Can I just update the recyclerview after I get a signal (call) from the external source by generating the Recyclerview again?

Comment: LiveData is used for this. When value is changed in LiveData, the onChange method is automatically called for LiveData you are observe in fragment.

Comment: Thanks for your comment adnandann. But I would like to do this without liveData. Is this possible? I had a look in your application and the complexitiy is overwhelmingly high. You created so many additional classes and methods only for an update. I assume that I would need more than 30 hours to learn such an extremely complex approach like the LiveData as you used in you app.

Comment: Hi adnandann. Thanks for your comment. Do you have any comments about my last comment? I'd appreciate any further comment from you. So basically I would like to know if I can trigger an update of a RecyclerView without the live data and model view approach and if so, how can I do this?

Comment: Is it not possible that the 'external' source just sends something like an update signal and the class with the RecyclerView just has something like a listener (compared to buttoms) and whenever this update signals is sent the RecyclerView Class uses an update function to update the RecyclerView. This approach would be quite easy and - as with buttoms - you could have different update signals and different listeners.

Comment: The way you tried to do it I have not seen anywhere and I think it is wrong ... Search google for communication between fragments without viewModel. For this you should use interfaces. In the application that I made, you have three simple ways to do itwith viewModel... If you want to do this job, you have to constantly learn new things ... it's not too complicated, read the tutorial several times with thinking...

Comment: Thanks adnandann for your further comment and effort. I really appreciate it. Well basically your application contains a lot of code and classes only for a small application. When considering that I have more than 30 fragments and I have to do this for all of them, this is just too time consuming. Further, the complexity of the livedata and Viewmodel approach is quite high. I tried to learn it with your application and a tutorial but there a so many things you have to do such that this is not easy at all.

Comment: Create a new application and try to type the code from my application only for the third option (without database) to understand how things work... if you don't understand everything send an email with a short list of questions for example "Why this like this", without a lot of text please, just simple question

Comment: Do you maybe know a good tutorial for LiveData and ViewModel (not the the official documentation of Andorid; I mostly do not like them)?

Comment: In your case you have only one activity and you create only one ViewModel in which you can have one LiveData to refresh fragments and you can only use it, it's very simple. Viewmodel is a data holder and liveData is a type of data that responds to changes within itself and calls onChange method that you implement in fragments, easily. that's why I'm telling you to type the code from my application only for the third option (package "simple"). One ViewModel and One LiveData in it

Comment: Thanks adnandann for your comment. Bascially I have use a single Activity multiple Fragment approach (as recommended by google). So in my single activity there are always other fragments in it. If I design a ViewModel and a LiveData for this Activity, I would have to always get to know which Fragment is being displayed and based on that I would have to use a specified ViewModel and LiveData. I do not think that just one ViewModel and LiveData is enough

Comment: Which of those classes from your app are you referring to? You have many classes in the simple folder (as with the others): adapter, view, viewmodel, model. What is the difference between model and viewmodel? And do you also use LiveData in the simple example?

Comment: Model is, for example Item, User, Player, Airplane, Car, Whatever... ViewModel is data holder for View/s, and holds all data (all models) used in View/s (Activity or fragments)... Try to create app with package simple and related classes. There is (Mutable)LiveData<Integer> "fragment" that I used to switch fragments in activity.

Comment: Thanks for the comment adnandann. Well I in fact had a look into your code but as said many time before, for me it is just really difficult to understand and I have just too many questions sucht that I do not know where to start asking. This is why picked up some questions. I also read the link to the tutorial that you mentioned but for me this whole concept is not really intuitive. You need so many methods and classes. This is why I keep asking (and searching) for other solutions because I somehow can't imagine that updating a recyclerView needs such complex approaches.

Comment: I still have huge difficulties trying to understand how I could integrate your code into my application and generally to undestand how I can use ViewModel and LiveData themselves and in the singleActivity multiple Fragment approach. I do not see how you use the singleActivity multiple Fragment approach and in your fragments you seem to create Activities (onActivityCreated method) which I do not understand at all.

Comment: You don't have to integrate into your application, first try to make a new one where you will try to learn how it works. That's why I told you to try to type the code from the package "simple" into new application. There are one activity, 3 fragments and one viewmodel. fragment replacement goes via the viewmodel... And what is not clear to you you can ask by email

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try to search for good tutorials about the viewmodel and livedata. Just from your application I can't understand what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the offer with the e-mail. I really appreciate your effort and helpfullness. Unfortunately I have to admit that I do not understand most of your code. Because of this I would have to ask more than 20 questions which does not make sense

Comment: Programming is learned by typing code, not by reading... I'm sorry but I can't help you more than I already am...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Well if you do not understand at all what you are typing, then it does not make sense as far as I see it. This is why I will now try to find some good tutorials or to even look for a completely other, less complex solution.

Comment: Thanks for your tremendous effort and help. Altough I will most probably not use your answer, I accepted it such that you get the points which you definitely deserve for your great effort that I really appreciate.

Comment: Thanks, if you do this job in the future one day you will come to mvvm pattern and learn this ... I will be glad if you open this answer and read the whole with comments and leave your opinion... happy coding